# Compiler not recognizing defined type

Tags: f#

For some reason F# won't recognize a type I have defined. I have a couple of types:

```
type point = int * int
type colour = int * int * int

type figure =
  | Circle of point * int * colour
  | Rectangle of point * point * colour
  | Mix of figure * figure
```

The `point` and `colour` types work fine, but when I try to compile a function like:

```
let testFig : figure =
    (50,50), 45, (255,0,0)
```

the  compiler throws an `fs001` exception, and says it expected `figure` but got `(int*int) * int * (int*int*int)` (Which is part of figure!).

I am a little lost and can't see why it's not working.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? How would you distinguish between creating a `Circle` and a `Rectangle` for example?

Comment: The type is to be used in a function, which uses patern maching, so the difference should just be defining it as `let testCircle = (50,50), 45, (255,0,0)` or `let testRect = (0,0), (50,50) (255,0,0)`, for example. Then the pattern matching can get to all the parameters

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread them as having the same payload type, because they both ended with `int` I guess. In any case my point was that they _can_ have the same type of payload, and if they do you have to distinguish them some other way. That's what the names are for. Otherwise this can easily be answered by reading [the language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions). It's not a bad idea to get into the habit of referring to that when you have questions about the basic language concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a `figure` value, you need to specify the name of the case that you want to create. For example, if you want to create `Circle` you need to write:

```
let testFig : figure =
    Circle((50,50), 45, (255,0,0))
```

Without the `Circle` constructor, you just create a value `(50,50), 45, (255,0,0)`, which has a type `(int * int) * int * (int * int * int)`. This is the same as `point * int * color` (because `point` and `color` are just aliases).